# Repositioning current Terminal window using a command

Tags: bash

I have tried repositioning the window with -geometry but that way a new window is created which is not what I am looking for. A command that suits what I need is printf'\e[3;0;0t'(moves the window in the top left corner of the screen) unfortunatly I need the window to go to all of the corners of the screen, but I was unable to find the ANSI escape code for the other three positions I need . Are there any other ways to move the current window without external tools and if not can someone enlighten me what are the ANSI escape codes for the other corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xdotool`.

To move the current window to the top left:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0
```

To move to the top right (you may need a larger number):

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 2000 0
```

To move to the bottom right:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 2000 2000
```

To move to the bottom left:

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 2000
```

Comment: For Terminal on Mac, you can use an osascript, `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to set bounds of front window to {0, 26, 1280, 1440}'`